# Using a DLL and header files written in cpp in a C# project

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll

I have a dll and header files but nothing else, and I want to use the library's functionality in a C# project. I could not use "DllImport" because the functions I wanted to use return an object whose class also is of the library. The wrapper examples I found include the examples which are written by knowing the body of the headers, but I do not have source files. How can I use the dll and header files? I will be thankful if anyone can help me.

Comment: Can you add your header files so that we can think of a solution?

Comment: indeed, there is no trivial way to import an unmanaged dll into a managed project and depending on the size and type of what is to import you'll either have to do your imports and create a class wrapper or make an intermediate managed c++ wrapper. You can at least note that there is no convenient one click solution to your problem